# AD FS 2.0 Event 206: "The Federation Service could not fulfill the token-issuance request"

Tags: saml, wif, adfs, adfs2.0

I am getting a strange error from ADFS 2.0 event Log as follows:

---

"The Federation Service could not fulfill the token-issuance request because the relying party 'https://my-relying-party' is missing a WS-Federation Passive endpoint address.

Relying party: https://my-relying-party

This request failed.

User Action

Use the AD FS 2.0 Management snap-in to configure a WS-Federation Passive endpoint on this relying party."

---

This happens after SAML response is verified successfully by ADFS 2.0 but apparently fails to issue a token for the relying party application.

I configured in ADFS 2.0 both IDP and SP as SAML 2.0 so I don't understand why is WS-Federation endpoint is expected?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Is your web application talking the WS-Federation protocol or the SAML protocol (SAML-P)?  If your web application is based on WIF, then you are using WS-Federation.  Note that both protocols use SAML *tokens*.

If your application talks the WS-Federation protocol, then in your AD FS Relying Party Trust you need to set the WS-Federation endpoint(s).  If it talks the SAML protocol, you need to set the SAML protocol endpoint(s).

Based on your error message, your application probably talks WS-Federation, therefore you need to set the WS-Federation endpoint.

Comment: - My IDP talks SAML 2.0. 
- ADFSv2 is configured with SAML endpoints for both Relying Party Trust and Claims Provider Trust (each contains a single SAML endpoint)

Sorry.. I am not sure what my web application talks. I created a new ASP.NET project using VS 2010 and copied web.config from the following URL: http://alt.pluralsight.com/wiki/default.aspx/Keith/SettingUpADFSSampleApp.html

I couldn't find any template in VS 2010 for SAML consumer Web Application, so I am playing around to find the correct solution.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The integration between your SAML 2.0 SP (ADFSv2) and your RP Application is done via WS-Federation Passive Requester Profile. So you'll need to setup your application to receive the WS-Fed Response and parse it appropriately. You'll also have to configure ADFSv2 to generate this message as well (per the error message you received).

Hope this helps -
Ian

Comment: That explains the error message.. Thanks a lot!
I'll try adding a WS-Fed endpoint to the relying party in ADFSv2 and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the web application url to the endpoints in the properties of you relying party.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

add ws-federation passive reference manually or in federation file will solve the problem.

Please let me know if you need detail guidance.